# How to get the updated entry string from a toplevel window before the tkinter main loop ends?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a toplevel window that pops up and asks you for your name. When you enter your name and click ok it should put the name in the `entry1_value` and close itself. Then I print the variable while keeping the empty (in this snippet of code) main window running. The problem is that it prints the `'Empty String'` on the first print and then only the input on the second one.

Here I'm just printing the information so I see if it registers it but I will use it somewhere later.

Also, in reality I just need the updated information placed outside in any way without the main window closing.

Here is the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

BUTTON_FONT = ('Lato', 16)

class NameInputBox:
    entry1_value = 'Empty String'
    def __init__(self, text):
        
        self.window = tk.Toplevel()
        self.window.wm_title("Input Name.")

        self.label_message = tk.Label(self.window, text = text, font = (BUTTON_FONT, 20))

        self.frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.window)
        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(self.frame1, font = BUTTON_FONT, width = 10)
        self.button_message = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="Ok", command = lambda: self.name_input_box_exit(self.window))
        
        self.entry1.pack(side = 'left', padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.button_message.pack(side = 'left', pady = 5, padx = 5)

        self.label_message.pack(side = 'top', pady = 10, padx = 10)
        self.frame1.pack(side = 'bottom', pady = 10, padx = 10)


    def name_input_box_exit(self, window):
        self.entry1_value = self.entry1.get()
        self.entry1.delete(0,tk.END)

        self.window.destroy()    

box1 = NameInputBox('Input the Name:')

print(box1.entry1_value)
tk.mainloop()
print(box1.entry1_value)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with this code?  The first `print()` occurs far too early for there to have been any user input yet, but the second one ought to be working just fine.

Comment: Yeah, but the second print happens only when you close the tkinter window. I'm not sure how to get the input and get it out of the class without needing to close the main window.

Comment: You should do whatever you need to do with the entered name from within `name_input_box_exit()`.  There's no point at the top level of your code corresponding to that event.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm going to forward the name and 2 other values to a different function that writes the name and scores to a file and sorts them based on score. Thank you for the idea. I will try getting the scores to the `name_input_box_exit()` and then just calling the function form there. Forgot to @ on the previous comment. sry

Comment: @jasonharper I did the top level thing just because I thought it would look nicer... honestly I could have just built an input on the main window itself. and then forgot the placement when I didn't need it anymore.

Comment: @jasonharper well I did what I said in my second comment to you. It works but doesn't solve the question I asked. At least it works though. I will leave the question in case anyone has any ideas. Thank you either way!

Comment: normally you should have main window - `tk.Tk()` - which runs `NameInputBox` and inside main window you should get value and use it. In your situation you don't have main window so I don't understand what you expect.

Comment: It seems you don't know how GUIs work. `mainloop()` starts GUI - it creates and displays window, get keyboard/mouse events from system and sends them to widgets. All code before `mainloop` is executed before you even see window - so it get empty value from Entry because it gets data before you even see window and before you can put any value in Entry. All code after `mainloop` is executed after you close window. If you want to use value then you have to do it after `mainloop()` or in function which you runs using `Button` (which you press after you put text in `Entry`).

Comment: if you will run it with main window then it should create `NameInputBox`, wait for it ends and later it can use value from `NameInputBox`. So better create code with main window because without main window it makes no sense.

Comment: BTW: you don't have to send `window` to `name_input_box_exit` because you can access it directly with `self.window`

Comment: @furas thank you, I didn't know how GUIs rly work. I just kind dove into it and figured things out as I went. It does make more sense now. In hindsight I should have probably watched a tutorial on yt :P Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me all your problem is because you try to use `Toplevel` without main window `Tk` - so you don't have code (`GUI`) which could get value from `Toplevel` when `mainloop` is still runing.

When you have main window then it can create `Toplevel`, make it `modal` (to wait for result), and later it can get value from `Toplevel` (when it is destroyed) when `mainloop` is still runing.

In example main window has button which runs function which creates `NameInputBox`, waits for its destroy, and gets value from `NameInputBox` and display in main window - and it does it all when `mainloop` is running.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class NameInputBox:

    entry_value = 'Empty String'
    
    def __init__(self, text):
        
        self.window = tk.Toplevel()
        self.window.wm_title("Input Name.")

        self.label = tk.Label(self.window, text=text)
        self.label.pack(side='top')

        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.pack(side='bottom')
        
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.entry.pack(side='left')

        self.button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Ok", command=self.name_input_box_exit)
        self.button.pack(side='left')

    def name_input_box_exit(self):
        # get value from widget and assign to variable
        self.entry_value = self.entry.get()

        self.window.destroy()    


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()

        self.label = tk.Label(self.window)
        self.label.pack()
        
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.window, text="Name", command=self.ask_name)
        self.button.pack()

        # the only `mainloop` in all code
        self.window.mainloop()
        
    def ask_name(self):
        # show Toplevel
        self.box = NameInputBox('Input the Name:')

        # set it modal (to wait for value)
        self.box.window.focus_set()   # take over input focus,
        self.box.window.grab_set()    # disable other windows while I'm open,
        self.box.window.wait_window() # and wait here until win destroyed

        # get value from Toplevel
        self.label['text'] = self.box.entry_value
        
MainWindow()
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about `modal`-s or `wait_window`. Another question. Why do you put `focus_set` and `grab_set` when the code would work fine with just `wait_window`. I understood that `grab_set` is used to prevent you from clicking on the main window. So it is useful to prevent you from opening more windows than you should and more probably :). What is `focus_set used here for? I saw some examples where it is used to select a widget as soon as a window opens. What purpose does it serve here?

Comment: I did try removing it from the code (the `focus_set`)... didn't really change anything apparent.

Comment: on some systems it may need `focus_set` to make window focused so you can use keys (ie. `tab`) to move from widget to widget without clicking mouse on window. If you use `entry` instead of `window` - `self.box.entry.focus_set()` - then you don't have click on `Entry` to start writing text.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!